# Игнорировать null при десериализации JSON

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Делаю мапинг JSON в иерархию объектов. Есть поле типа класса, которое в JSON может быть null. Jackson в спринге валится при попытке маппировать это нулевое поле в объект. Как сделать, чтобы если вложенный джейсон равен null, то и ссылка на соответствующий объект была null? @JsonIgnore работает только при сериализации, а я десериализую JSON.

Comment: вы используете Spring Boot ?

Comment: Смотря какой маппер вы используете. `Jackson`, `Gson`? Или что-то другое? Для каждого свои аннотации и настройки

Answer (score 4):

Если вы используете Spring boot, тогда это можно настроить в application.properties.

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false
```

Если у вас не spring boot приложение, тогда надо сделать бин со следующими настройками:

```
@Bean
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
            return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавь свой десериалайзер

```
public final class JsonWithNullDeserializer
    extends JsonNodeDeserializer
{
    @Override
    public JsonNode getNullValue(DeserializationContext ctxt)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

И задай этот десериалайзер везде где нужно

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonWithNullDeserializer.class)
```